# SQL Server - create timeout exception in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout, timeoutexception

I have a table-valued function.

Now, I need to do a test when this function (`SELECT` query) returns **Timeout exception**.

When I'm doing the test the functions works fine for me, so I was wondering if I can force **Timeout exception** in order to do a test.

If it can't be done within a function, can it be done at all?

Comment: No. Timeouts happen at the connection. The sql server engine will just run a query forever until it finishes. But what are you REALLY trying to do? This screams of being an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I'm trying to do a test when function takes too long to execute, and at the end throws timeout exception.

Comment: set time out to 1 and ensure your function runs longer than that

Comment: Again....the query engine has no concept of timeout. That is what the connection timeout property is for. It is not at all clear what your real objective is here.

Comment: set your connection time out to 1 and ensure your function runs longer than that.  I get it, you want to test the error condition.  You have to set things up to trigger it.  Set the connection timeout to 1 ms then connect and run a query that takes longer than that.  voila!  you'll get a timeout error.

Comment: Just add a WAITFOR in your function and it will run for as long as you want it to.

Comment: Sean, I don't think WAITFOR is allowed inside functions...

Comment: @user1443098, query executes under 1 second for me... I think 1 second is the smallest time

Comment: so, make up a query that is longer.  put in a loop.  this is just to test your error handler, anyway.  Are you using a unit test framework?

Comment: @user1443098, not using any test framework, just trying to manually test exception that some users have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can pass whatever value you want and it'll loop through until it reaches 0. Too high of a number throws an arithmetic error.

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.timeoutFunction(@P1 int)
RETURNS @table TABLE 
(
    Id int
)
AS

BEGIN

WHILE @P1 > 0 
BEGIN  
      SET @P1 -= 1
      INSERT INTO @table
      SELECT @P1
END
RETURN
END
```

**Call:**

```
SELECT * FROM timeoutfunction(1000000)
```

Comment: yea, that's what I did at the end - added while loop, and it did the job

Comment: @jovanM Good stuff, thought I'd throw in an example for posterity.